# How to check if the element in on screen on webpage and I also want a trigger when someone scrolls to that

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the element is on the screen. It MUST NOT involve any kind of scrolling. I just want to check if the element is on the screen. I have tried different codes out there. They work perfectly fine on Desktops but not on mobile phones.

This is my current code:

```
var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

if(wScroll > $('.services').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {

    $('.jstransitiononservices').each(function(i){

      setTimeout(function(){
      $('.jstransitiononservices').eq(i).addClass('is-showing');
      }, 150 * (i+1));  

    });

}
```

Comment: I mean I have to scroll a little bit in order to trigger an event. Obviously the view on desktops and mobiles are different. Refer here please: umerjaved1.base.pk

Comment: You can open the site.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` method on window scroll and you can look for `top` property of the returned object:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var target = $('.services')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(target, $(window).scrollTop());
  if (target.top <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('pre').html('Element is in view.');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='services'>services div</div>
<pre></pre>
```

This one with scroll:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var target = $('.services')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(target, window.innerHeight);
  if (target.top <= $(window).scrollTop() && target.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
    $('pre').html('Element is in view.');
  }
}).scroll(); // <----this triggers scroll on page load.
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:800px;
}
.services{margin:500px 0 0 0; border:solid 1px red;}
pre{position:fixed; left:0; top:0; width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='services'>services div</div>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: It works if the element is in view on page refresh. What if it gets into the view while using the website?

Comment: I meant I want to check if the element is already in view on page refresh or someone scroll to that too.

Comment: @UmerJaved then this can be used in `.scroll()` event.

Comment: but then it only checks for the trigger when someone scrolls.

Comment: You can use a trailing `.scroll()` see other snippet to see.

Comment: THis is my code. Please tell what changes should I make.

Comment: You can also add your html markup in your fiddle and reproduce the issue you are getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103279/discussion-between-umer-javed-and-jai).

Comment: Sorry javed chat is disabled in here, can't help you on it.

Comment: actually I have two platforms to open my site.
one is desktop
and other is mobile
when websites load on desktop it works perfectly fine.
but when I open my site on mobile
the event is not triggered
because when you're from the desktop. That element is not in the view so everyone has to scroll down.
so the trigger gets triggered
but when you're from the mobile.
that element is already in the view.
and you have to scroll down a little bit
then that trigger gets triggered
Please go to the website from mobile to understand the issue more clearly.
umerjaved1.base.pk